# VPN no conecta con el servidor (FortiClient)

Tags: vpn

Tengo un problema y es que no me puedo conectar por VPN al servidor usando el FortiClient VPN. Lo único que pasa es que al ingresar mi usuario y mi contraseña comienza a cargar pero al llegar al 100% de conexión me regresa al formulario para volver a ingresar mi contraseña, después de eso vuelvo a ingresarla y solo llega al status...98% y ya no avanza.

Ya quite mi antivirus, actualice mi windows, verifique los datos de acceso e instale varias veces el FortiClien VPN pero sigue sin conectarme. Exporte los logs y por mas que busco no encuentro una solución.

Logs:

```
info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 10168: fortissl_connect: device=ftvnic
info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 6128: PreferDtlsTunnel=0
error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 12320: error: poll_send_ssl ->SSL_get_error(): 5, try:1
error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 12320: error: poll_send_ssl -> WSAGetLastError():2746, try:1
error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 12320: error: poll_send_ssl ->data size: 86, try:1
error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 12320: [handle_driver_read_event]: error: poll_send
error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 12324: error: poll_recv_ssl -> SSL_get_error(): 5
error   sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 12324: error: poll_recv_ssl -> WSAGetLastError():2746
info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 12324: error: polling recv, try:1
info    sslvpn  FortiSslvpn: 9784: Ras: connection to fortissl terminated
```

Comment: https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=167181 -> "We resolved our issue by enabling TLS 1.1 and 1.2 in the Browser settings."

Answer (score 0):

Estimado pudiste solucionar el problema a mi tambien me empezo a dar el mismo error.

Estimado, pude solucionar el problema al parecer se presenta en la ultima versión del forticlient instale una más antigua y me pude conectar sin problemas

Comment: Recomiendo que leas [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos!

Comment: Y además, en los comentarios de la pregunta, ya os han puesto solución. Activar TLS 1.1 y 1.2 en las opciones del FortiClient.